# ¿Cómo instalar mi programa de Java en otra computadora?

Tags: java, ejecutar

Es un programa super básico para intentar ejecutarlo en otra PC, el cual solo cuenta cuantos clics das. Lo programé con JDK 14 (no sé si afecte).
Hice el archivo .jar, en mi computadora sí lo ejecuta correctamente el .jar pero al ejecutarlo en otra en la que únicamente instalé el JRE me da un error de "Java Virtual Machine".

¿Necesito algo más en la otra computadora?
¿Debería bajar mi JDK?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cuál es exactamente el error? Es probable que sí sea por la versión, la mayoría de computadoras (de acuerdo a lo que he visto y mi experiencia) se quedaron con Java 8, algunas ya tienen Java 9, pero nunca he visto una con Java 14 (por lo menos no de alguien que no sea programador)

Answer (score 0):

Antiguamente (hasta Java 8), lo común era generar un fichero jar y distribuirlo entre los usuarios, de tal manera que cualquier usuario que quisiera ejecutarlo necesitara instalar la JRE en su máquina.

Pero hoy día la forma de distribuir recomendada ha cambiado y lo normal es entregar un paquete que tenga todo lo necesario (JVM + librerías necesarias), de ese modo evitamos tener varias versiones del JRE instaladas si necesitamos ejecutar distintas aplicaciones ya antiguas.

Desde Java 14 el JDK incluye `jpackage`, que te permite crear un ejecutable con todo lo necesario para instalar la aplicación:

```
jpackage --input <path>/ \
  --name <nombreApp> \
  --main-jar <ficheroJar> \
  --main-class nombre.de.la.clase.MainApp \
  --type <tipo_de_instalador> (deb, rpm ,msi , exe, dmg)
```

Más información (en inglés) [aquí](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/343), donde según sea el sistema operativo donde quieras instalarlo te permitirá añadir opciones para crear un acceso directo en el escritorio, permitir durante la instalación elegir el directorio... etc